# Plotting Line Graph with JSON data, Android

Tags: java, android, json, graph

I'm total beginner in Android development and I'm doing app for class. My assigment is to display JSON data in application as text and graphs. I'm using Retrofit 2 to display it as text in one activity, but I'm having problems with graphs, I don't know how to do it (I'm still learning, everything I've done so far was with help from tutorials).

The data looks like this (this is an example):

```
{
"id": 1,
"measurements": [{
    "time": "18:25:43",
    "value": 25.4
},
{
    "time": "18:35:43",
    "value": 27.3
},
{
    "time": "18:45:21",
    "value": 26.3
},
{
    "time": "18:55:43",
    "value": 25.2
},
{
    "time": "19:05:43",
    "value": 25.2
},
{
    "time": "19:15:43",
    "value": 25.2
},
{
    "time": "19:25:43",
    "value": 24.9
}]
}
```

I've found [this](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jjoe64/graphview_demos/examples/SimpleLineGraph.java), but I'm not sure what to do next. Should I make two array lists with data(if that's the answer, how to do that?), or there's better solution that directly takes time and value and plots graph with time as X-axis and value as Y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution.

First you have to add in dependencies

```
dependencies{
  compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.3'
  ....}
```

Now in your xml add below code

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/chart1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And now in your Java code

```
ArrayList<Entry> x;
ArrayList<String> y;
private LineChart mChart;
public String TAG = "YOUR CLASS NAME";
```

Inside onCreate Method

```
    x = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    y = new ArrayList<String>();
    mChart = (LineChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mChart.setDescription("");
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    mChart.setPinchZoom(true);
    mChart.setMarkerView(mv);
    XAxis xl = mChart.getXAxis();
    xl.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setInverted(true);
    YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
    Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
    l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
```

Call this method on button click.

```
private void drawChart() {

    String tag_string_req = "req_chart";

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "YOUR URL",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("measurements");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            int value = jsonObject.getInt("value");
                            String date = jsonObject.getString("time");
                            x.add(new Entry(value, i));
                            y.add(date);

                        }
                        LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(x, "NAV Data Value");
                        set1.setLineWidth(1.5f);
                        set1.setCircleRadius(4f);
                        LineData data = new LineData(y, set1);
                        mChart.setData(data);
                        mChart.invalidate();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    strReq.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {

        @Override
        public void retry(VolleyError arg0) throws VolleyError {
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeout() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    strReq.setShouldCache(false);
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

AppController code as here

```
public class AppController extends Application {
public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static AppController mInstance;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

  public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
 }
```

Hope this will help you. If any issue faced let me know.

Comment: At the beginning I'm getting Failed to resolve: com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.3

Comment: okay, I've found solution to that problem, but now there a lot of "Cannot resolve method or variable". It happens on StringRequest, Method, Listener, ErrorListener, VolleyError, getMessage, setRetryPolicy, RetryPolicy, setShouldCache, AppController. Also, can I just put drawChart() in onCreate instead of calling it on button click?

Comment: TAG and mv (mv in  mChart.setMarkerView(mv)) are also red.

Comment: You have to import volley lib in dependencies and remove this -  mChart.setMarkerView(mv)

Comment: Also you have to create AppController class

Comment: thanks, but TAG is still red and when I create AppController class getInstance in the last line becomes red

Comment: app crashes, am I doing something wrong? I copied everything, just replaced "YOUR CLASS NAME" with "Graphs" (I copied code in class Graphs.java) and "YOUR URL" with MainActivity.BASE_URL+"sensors/1" (I did the same thing with URL for text display of the data on another activity and it works there)

Comment: my laptop is slow, so I'm trying app directly on the phone,it generates apk without any problems, but when i click Graphs button on main screen to switch to graphs activity app crahes

Comment: and i forgot to mention it, I added drawChart() to onCreate()

Comment: share log cat message

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{smarthome.com.smarthome/smarthome.com.smarthome.Grafovi.Grafovi}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void smarthome.com.smarthome.Grafovi.AppController.addToRequestQueue(com.android.volley.Request, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: I also had to change int value = jsonObject.getInt("value"); because values in JSON are double, now it's: double value = jsonObject.getDouble("value"); float value2 = (float) value;

Comment: Shane do you have a solution to the problem? Here is the problem again: **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void smarthome.com.smarthome.Graphs.AppController.addToRequestQu‌​eue(com.android.voll‌​ey.Request, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

Comment: I just tried to start it again and the same thing happens, NullPointer Exception; do you what is causing this because it works fine for displaying data with retrofit.

Comment: If it works with retrofit, then go with it and leave volley behind.

Comment: Okay, then what should I delete or add?

Comment: okay, but I don't know what to add and delete, retrofit works because I found how to do it on the internet, It's my first using it and plotting graph with Android and I'm doing everything with code I've on the internet, graph is the one thing that there no code for and I just don't know how to do it. Could you please help me?

Comment: do you email where i can send it to or some other sort of communication because it won't fit here in comments

Comment: Problem solve, take update from Git of your project.

Comment: LineData data = new LineData(y, set1);
this line does not accept y as list of strings. so unable to set the dates as graph axis data.\