# Get JSON Data and put it into X/Y data to create graph

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to create a graph using JSON data with Volley. I was going to follow the answer from this question [Plotting Line Graph with JSON data, Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582586/plotting-line-graph-with-json-data-android) on creating the graph. My issue is I do not know how to get the data from the JSON. As you can see below, inside the `market_cap` is an array that stores array data. How can I get all the data inside `market_cap` and store it into X and Y to use for the graph? Inside the array the first value is a date and the second value is price.

JSON

```
{  
   "market_cap":[  
      [  
         1521320052000,
         53961098802
      ],
      [  
         1521330851000,
         54300167307
      ],
      [  
         1521334452000,
         51916531911
      ],
      [  
         1521345251000,
         51207867582
      ]
   ]
}
```

Volley Code

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "URL",
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("market_cap");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    x.add(//add date);
                    y.add(//add value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `jsonArray.getLong(index)`

Comment: you have nested json array. you can get x as jsonArray.getJSONArray(i).getLong(0) and y as jsonArray.getJSONArray(i).getLong(1)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) which is easier and simpler to implement. In your case, you can consider parsing the JSON like the following.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MarketPrice mp = gson.fromJson(response, MarketPrice.class);
        mapTheTimeVsPriceGraph(mp);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So you need to have a `MarketPrice` class to parse the value from the JSON in this class. So the `MarketPrice` class should look like this.

```
public class MarketPrice implements Serializable {
    public String[][] market_cap;
}
```

And the `mapTheTimeVsPriceGraph` function should look like.

```
List<Long> time = new ArrayList<Long>();
List<Integer> price = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void mapTheTimeVsPriceGraph(MarketPrice mp) {   
    for (int i = 0; i < mp.length; i++) {
        time.add(Long.parseLong(mp[i][0]));
        time.add(Integer.parseInt(mp[i][1]));
    }
}
```

I have not tested the code. However, I think it should work and put you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GSON solution Reaz Murshed suggested or alternatively, you could step through the array and get the values directly. The GSON method is more elegant, but I you just want to get the values, the following example will suffice and no need to import GSON.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("market_cap");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray jsonData = jsonObject.getJSONArray(i);
            if(jsonData == 2){
                x.add(jsonData.optLong(0, -1));
                y.add(jsonData.optLong(1, -1));
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The first element "market_cap" is a `JSONArray` and the child of the "market_cap" element is also a `JSONArray`. So after getting the `JSONArray` from "market_cap"  you can iterate through each following `JSONArray` inside "jsonArray". Then since you need x,y pairs for your graph just check to see if the `JSONArray` I call "jsonData" has exactly 2 elements. Now you can use the `JSONArray` index to access the data. I suggest you use the `optLong()` method with a fallback value--that way if anything goes wrong you will have a value. I used -1 in this example, but you may what to use a different value.