# How to PUT the data into Piechart of MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, retrofit2, mpandroidchart, android-studio-2.3

yesterday i tried to put the data(Decimal Number, String) into Piechart of MPAndroidchart but i got the problem where if i added The field stock(decimal number), and item_name(String) in "yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(...)" then  both not displaying. once more if added one field item_name(String)only in "yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(...)" it displaying without stock and it make me confused for this problem.note(to put data i'm using method "GET" of retrofit2).

This some data with json format from database and it dynamic:

```
{"success":true,
    "result":
        [{"id":"1","item_name":"Salt","stock":"6.5"},
         {"id":"2","item_name":"Sugar","stock":"50.8"},
         {"id":"3","item_name":"Coffe ","stock":"40"},
         {"id":"4","item_name":"Rice","stock":"30.8"
         }]
}
```

this my code in ListActivity:

```
ItemService itemService = APIClient.getClient().create(ItemService .class);
Call<responseItem > call = itemService.getFindAll();
ResponseItem responseItem = response.body();
    if (responseItem.getSuccess().equals("true")) {
        itemList = response.body().getResult();
        List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<PieEntry> yEntrys = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();

        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
        //this is place i added some field
        yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(i, itemList .get(i).getStock(), itemList.get(i).getItem_name()));

        }

        PieDataSet dataset = new PieDataSet(yEntrys,null);
        dataset.setSliceSpace(3);
        dataset.setValueTextSize(5);

        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

        for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

        colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());
        dataset.setColors(colors);

        Legend legend = pieChart.getLegend();
        legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.DEFAULT);
        legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.LEFT_OF_CHART);
        legend.setTextSize(8);

        Description description = new Description();
        description.setText("Stocks Description of Items");

        pieChart.setDescription(description);  
        description.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        pieChart.setRotationEnabled(true);

        pieChart.setHoleRadius(25f);
        pieChart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(0);
        pieChart.setCenterText("Chart");
        pieChart.setCenterTextSize(10);
        pieChart.setDrawEntryLabels(true);
        pieChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(5);
        pieChart.setTransparentCircleColor(5);

        pieData = new PieData(dataset);
        pieData.setValueTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        pieChart.setData(pieData);
        pieChart.animateY(2000);
        pieChart.highlightValues(null);
        pieChart.invalidate();

        }else{
    Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, responseItem.getSuccess(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

My answer is How to do Fixing this problems. Thanks All.

Comment: Hi Senior Programmer , I need help , Thanks.

Comment: can anyone helping me for solving this problem?

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582586/plotting-line-graph-with-json-data-android